# Как сложить время Php

Tags: php

Есть две переменные:

```
$first = "13:00";
$second = "00:25";
$new_date = date('H:i', strtotime("+$second minuts", strtotime($first))); // Не работает!(
```

как их сложить чтобы получилось 13:25?

Comment: Сложить как даты? Из обеих делаешь даты, а лучше из одной дату, из второй timespan (если оно водится в PHP), и складываешь, потом экспортируешь в строку правильного формата.

Answer (score 1):

Второй аргумент у strtotime должен быть не строкой, а таймштампом.
И часы и минуты придется разделить самому

```
$first = "13:10";
$second = "00:25";
list($h, $m) = explode(':', $first);
echo $new_date = date('H:i', strtotime("+$h hour $m minute", strtotime($second)));  // 13:35
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот такое выражение дает правильный ответ. Более подробно можно почитать здесь http://php.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=45167

```
$res = strtotime('13:00') + strtotime('00:25') -strtotime("00:00:00");
echo date('H:i',$res);
```

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку: Зачем последний `-strtotime("00:00:00")`?

Comment: Отнимаем сегодняшнюю дату, чтобы получить только время. Специально привел ссылку где это уже написано.