# Как корректно прибавить дату в Php

Tags: php

Имеются переменные

```
$first = "23-07-2015 19:28";
$second = "48:03";
```

Как получить при сложении 25-07-2015 19:30 ???

Comment: вот ваш вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437355/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-php там же  и ответ

Answer (score 1):

Привести строки к типу `Date`, посредством функции `date_create_from_format()` и просто сложить математически, т. к. `date` - кол-во секунд. Далее, используя функцию `date()` привести полученный результат к строке

[Справка по функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: так?$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $first);

Comment: только не забыть вычесть дату